# OpenERP Payroll Loan Deduction

Tags: python, odoo

Can anyone help me with a formula or process to deduct loans taken by employees from their salary/wages please? Thanks

Comment: how you want to deduct loan amount? what is rule to deduct loan amount?

Comment: So I would like to deduct a fixed or a percentage amount from the salary every month? Any procedure would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Rule of Loan deduction in Salary Rule and specify Amount type there.

This new rule would be effective in Employee Salary sleep structure which has taken loan from the company.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Contract for employee by configuring wage and Salary structure. In Salary structure, Add a new rule for Home loan with Deduction type and assign Fixed / Percentage amount with negative (-) sign as its Deduction. Go to the Employee Payslip, select an employee and click on Compute Sheet. You will see salary structure in Salary Computation tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a rule like this and add this in salary structures of employee

It is fixed example, when you click in compute sheet it calculate deduction from amount

[image]